# cannot build blender version 3.1.2

Tags: python, blender

I cloned blender and checkout `v3.1.2` (`git checkout v3.1.2`)
then `make update` then I have below error

```
python3 ./build_files/utils/make_update.py
Blender git repository is in detached HEAD state, must be in a branch
make: *** [update] Error 1
```

how to build blender for python specific version?

Answer (score 0):

You are in a detached `HEAD` state, it means that you're not currently on any branch.

Here is how to download a specific version

```
git clone https://git.blender.org/blender.git
```

we go in the directory

```
cd blender
```

then `checkout` the specific version, for example `v3.1.2`

```
git checkout v3.1.2
```